# Bernoulli's Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the equation:

$6y^2 dx - x(2x^3 + y) dy = 0$

Solution:

Since the equation is linear to the variable $x$, I group the terms according to powers of $x$:

(1) $6y^2 dx + xy dy - 2x^4  dy  = 0$

The terms of the equation containing, respectively, $dx$, $x$, and $x^n$ where $n = 4$. I divided the terms by $x^4$:

(2) $(6y^2)(x^{-4}) dx + (x^{-3})(y) dy - 2 dy = 0$

I am confused on whether what variable the equation will be linear. Is the equation linear on $y^2$? or $x^{-3}$, since equation (1) is linear on variable $x$? On the other hand, I am also confused on the solution on the book (Rainville, E. D., Bedient, P. E. (1989). Elementary Differential Equation. 7th Edition. New York: MacMillan Publishing Company). According to the book, equation (1) can equally be treated as $6y^2 x^2 dx - x^3(2 + y) dy = 0$ when multiplied by $x^2$. How does $x^2$ obtained? Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Represent it in the form of dx/dy, then divide by x^4. Replace 1/x^3 by t , then it becomes a linear differential eqn.

Comment: HYDROGEN, your first line should be $6y^2 dx  \color {blue}{ - xy dy} - 2x^4  dy  = 0$

Answer (score 1):

$$6y^2 dx - x(2x^3 + y) dy = 0$$
$$6y^2x' - xy = 2x^4$$
This is Bernouilli's equation
$$2y^2z'  + zy = -2$$
Where $z=\dfrac 1 {x^3}$
$$(\sqrt y z)'=-y^{-3/2}$$
$$z(y)=\frac 2 y + \frac C {\sqrt y }$$
$$x^3(y)=\frac  {y }{C\sqrt y +2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Another idea: group the original equation be the degrees of the terms
$$
0=[6y^2\,dx-xy\,dy]−2x^4\,dy=-x^7y\,d(x^{-6}y)-2x^4\,dy
$$
This now is separable,
$$
0=\frac{d(x^{-6}y)}{x^{-3}y^{1/2}}+2\frac{dy}{y^{3/2}}
$$